# Create separate groups on a column with same values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DF like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'token': {0: 'FATHER', 1: 'MILTON', 2: 'IAN', 3: 'SMITH', 4: '.', 5: 'JOINTLY', 6: 'WITH', 7: 'BROTHER', 8: 'GREG', 9: 'I', 10: 'SMITH'}, 'tag': {0: 'O', 1: 'PERSON', 2: 'PERSON', 3: 'PERSON', 4: 'O', 5: 'O', 6: 'O', 7: 'O', 8: 'PERSON', 9: 'PERSON', 10: 'PERSON'}})

    token   tag
0   FATHER  O
1   MILTON  PERSON
2   IAN     PERSON
3   SMITH   PERSON
4   .       O
5   JOINTLY P
6   WITH    O
7   BROTHER O
8   GREG    PERSON
9   I       PERSON
10  SMITH   PERSON
```

What I want to do is to group all the consecutive rows with the tag being PERSON and concatenate the tokens.

Expected output:

```
  token
0 MILTON IAN SMITH
1 GREG I SMITH
```

Answer (score 2):

Create unique groups with consecutive values of `PERSON` by `shift` and `cumsum` and filter by mask for matched rows, then pass to `groupby` with [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) and `join`:

```
m = df['tag'].eq('PERSON')
s = m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum()[m]

df = df.groupby(s)['token'].apply(' '.join).reset_index(drop=True).to_frame('token')
print (df)
              token
0  MILTON IAN SMITH
1      GREG I SMITH
```

Comment: I was trying to remember this line of code 'm.ne(m.shift()).cumsum()[m]' I'm pretty sure I've seen you used it before. Thanks Jezrael :-)

Answer (score 1):

jezrael's answer is good enough. I'll throw another solution here. The key is to create labels for each person group.

Create gruops,

```
group = df['tag'].ne('PERSON').cumsum().where(df['tag'].eq('PERSON'))
```

Output

```
0     NaN
1     1.0
2     1.0
3     1.0
4     NaN
5     NaN
6     NaN
7     NaN
8     5.0
9     5.0
10    5.0
```

Then,

```
df['token'].groupby(group).apply(' '.join).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Note that groupby will automatically drop groups that are lebelled as `NaN`.